Solving the Riccati equation with constant coefficients $y^\prime = a y^2 + b y + c$
Is there a standard way of expressing the solution for the Riccati equation with constant coefficients $y^\prime = a y^2 + b y + c$ subject to initial condition $y(0) = 0$?

In general, you have this, but for this problem, you can do $\frac{dy}{ay^2 + by + c} = dx$

Write it as $y'=a(y-r_1)(y-r_2)$ and consider $u=\frac{y-r_1}{y-r_2}$ and its derivative. The DE for $u$ has an easier form.

You'll also want to consider the case where $ay^2+by+c$ has a double root separately.

This is a separable ODE.
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=ay^2+by+c\quad\implies\quad dx=\frac{dy}{ay^2+by+c}$$
$$x=\int \frac{dy}{ay^2+by+c}dx=\frac{2}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2ay+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}} \right)+C$$
$$y=\frac{1}{2a}\left(-b+\sqrt{4ac-b^2}\tan\left(\frac12 \sqrt{4ac-b^2}(x-C) \right)\right)$$
Condition: $y(0)=0\quad\implies\quad C=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}} \right)$

This is the case for negative discriminant. Now add the cases for positive and zero discriminant

@Lutz Lehmann : If you think that  the above incomplete solution is not sufficient to show what is the method to solve this kind of separable ODE it is up to you to add the case of negative discriminant. This would be welcome.

The other cases are of course contained in this formula if you use the tangent with complex arguments and treat the limit to zero correctly.

Of course. Or one uses hyperbolic functions.

Putting focus more on the fact that this is a Riccati DE and not that it is separable, one solution method parametrizes the solutions as $y=-\frac{u'}{au}$ to get
$$
y'=-\frac{u''}{au}+\frac{u'^2}{au^2}=\frac{u'^2}{au^2}-\frac{bu'}{au}+c
$$
resulting in the linear DE
$$
0=u''-bu'+acu.
$$
Now apply the solution method for linear DE with constant coefficients.
